# How do I get a class by clicking an image with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I'm currently working on a web page for a smart home system.
I have a main switch for every room / device to turn it on or off
[as you can see here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gazdu.png)

The data is being handled by jQuery and all device / room data is stored in a JSON file.

Now I need to identify which button I'm clicking and which 'id' it belongs too within the JSON file.

I have already made sure that each of these switches has got a class with the JSON 'id' in the name, so my current situation looks like this:

```
<img class="switch switch_id1" src="img/svgs/toggle-on_dark.svg">
```

The JSON entry looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "room": "Kitchen",
    "name": "Light controller",
    "favourite": false,
    "rating": 3,
    "select_1": "Off",
    "select_2": "On",
    "select_3": "Dinner",
    "select_4": "Bar",
    "category": "switch",
    "on": true
}
```

I would like to create a function that detects the JSON 'id' of the switch I'm clicking by reading its HTML class, but how do I do that?

I will also need to do the same thing for the 'favourisation' icon and the rating (those 5 dots), but I guess the procedure will be the same for that.

Comment: I would suggest using a custom `data` attribute for this and not a class

Comment: @empiric I had seen that as well, but I still don't know how to read an attribute just by clicking on an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use a `data-` attribute for that, and if using jquery it's especially easy to read

```js
$(document).on('click','.switch',function(){
    console.log($(this).data("switchid"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="switch" data-switchid="1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
```

You can do this without jQuery too

```js
document.querySelector(".switch").onclick = function(){
   console.log(this.getAttribute("data-switchid"));
}
```

```html
<img class="switch" data-switchid="1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
```

Comment: thanks a ton! Now I finally understand data-attributes thanks to your example.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that, as stated, it's probably better with a data attribute, but it's quite easy with a class actually, it's probably quicker than switching all your code to data (and all its quirks that can come from messing `attr` and `data` calls):

```js
$('img').on('click', function(){
  var test = /switch_id(\d+)/.exec(this.className);
  if(test){
    var id = test[1];
    console.log(id);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="switch switch_id1" src="https://placeimg.com/160/120/any">
<img class="switch switch_id2" src="https://placeimg.com/160/120/any">
```